# Which CPU is utilized when seraching a server from an end user machine?

Tags: central-processing-unit, network-attached-storage

When an end user desktop that is connected to a network runs a normal Windows Explorer search of a network location (\\server-name), which CPU is utilized? The CPU on the end user machine, or the CPU on that server?
Navigate to server
[image]

Run search of a word
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both, the client needs to actively request the data and the server needs to load and return it.

Comment: Well okay yes, both machines are on. Their CPUs are running. Duh. But which machine is more heavily utilized for the search function? I would find it hard to believe if it was exactly 50/50.